# QUdpSocket writeDatagram() returns error 7 (Unable to send a message)

Tags: qt, qtnetwork

I am working on Qt app, which is basically `QTcpServer` containing several `QTcpSocket` and `QUdpSocket` objects. Now, once app is started, the `QTcpServer` is started and for now, for simplicity `QUdpSocket` is started and I am sending broadcast data to `LAN` every **5 seconds** using this `QUdpSocket`, which works fine:

```
void UeMainWindow::ueSlotNetworkInformationBroadcastTimerTimeout()
{
    QList<QVariant> parameters;
    QByteArray datagram;

    parameters.append(this->ueTcpServer()->ueServerIPv4().toString());
    parameters.append(QString::number(this->ueTcpServer()->ueServerPort()));

    datagram=UePOSCommProtocol::ueEncodeCommand(UePosCommProtocolArch::UeCommand::CMD_GET_NETWORK_SETTINGS,
                                                parameters);

    if(this->ueNetworkInformationSocket()->writeDatagram(datagram.data(),
                                                         datagram.size(),
                                                         QHostAddress::Broadcast,
                                                         20000)>0)
    {
        this->ueSlotAddEventInfoLog(UeLogEntryType::INFO,
                                    tr("Newtwork information data")
                                    .append(" ")
                                    .append(datagram.toHex())
                                    .append(" ")
                                    .append(tr("sent via broadcast")));
    }
    else
    {
        this->ueSlotAddEventInfoLog(UeLogEntryType::ERROR,
                                    tr("Error sending Newtwork information data")
                                    .append(" ")
                                    .append(datagram.toHex())
                                    .append(" ")
                                    .append(tr("via broadcast"))
                                    .append(" ")
                                    .append(tr("with error"))
                                    .append(" ")
                                    .append(QString::number(this->ueNetworkInformationSocket()->error()))
                                    .append(" ")
                                    .append("(")
                                    .append(this->ueNetworkInformationSocket()->errorString())
                                    .append(")"));
    }   // if
}   // ueSlotNetworkInformationBroadcastTimerTimeout
```

Now, I am trying to simulate network disconnection with turning off Wi-Fi while app is running. The app detects network change via [QNetworkConfigurationManager::onfigurationChanged(const QNetworkConfiguration &config](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkconfigurationmanager.html#configurationChanged) and restarts server binding it to `localhost`:

```
void UeMainWindow::ueSlotNetworkOnlineStateChanged(bool isOnline)
{
    this->ueSlotAddEventInfoLog(isOnline?UeLogEntryType::INFO:UeLogEntryType::ERROR,
                                tr("Network online state changed").append(" ")
                                                                  .append(isOnline?tr(" ONLINE "):tr(" OFFLINE ")));
    if(!isOnline)
    {
        this->ueTcpServer()->ueRestart(QHostAddress::LocalHost,
                                       20000);
    }   // if
}   // ueSlotNetworkOnlineStateChanged
```

Once this is done, I again try to send data via `QUdpSocket` with first code chunk, but I get [error 7](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#SocketError-enum):
[image: QUdpSocket::writeDatagram() error]
Why? Is it even possible to send `Broadcast` via `loopback`/`localhost`?

Comment: [Please don't abuse `code formatting`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/349538)

Comment: @DonaldDuck hmm, where did I abuse code formatting by your opinion?

Comment: You formatted "Qt" and "Wi-Fi" as code, but none of those words are actually code. You might want to read [this Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/349538) and its answers.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?